# How to convert Open Xml Math Equation to MathML

Tags: c#, openxml, mathml

How can i convert OpenXml math equation (m:OMathPara tag) to MathML.
Does there exist any converter library?

My problem is importing data from MS Word and saving it in database and viewing in webpage.
I have already imported as text with openxml but i cant import Math equation. I think, for html page math equation must be MathML or image format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Word includes an `omml2mml.xsl` XSLT stylesheet that does this transformation (which is how it places MathML on the clipboard)  eg on my system it is

```
\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OMML2MML.XSL
```